# Generate SQL query for all datewise for each employee

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two table like -

tbl1

owner_id   owner_name

---

```
  1         a
  2         b
  3         c
```

tbl2

```
can_id   CAn_Name   owner_id   createddate   
------------------------------------------    
11        aa     1          10/3/2014
12        bb     2          9/3/2014
13        cc     3          8/3/2014 
14        dd     3          7/3/2014
15        ee     2          9/3/2014
16        ff     1          5/3/2014
17        gg     2          4/3/2014
```

I want result like this:

```
CREATEDATE             a                         b                  c        
----------------------------------------------------------------------    
1/3/2014               0                        0                   0
2/3/2014               0                        0                   0
3/3/2014               0                        0                   0
4/3/2014               0                        1                   0
5/3/2014               1                        0                   0
6/3/2014               0                        0                   0
7/3/2014               0                        0                   1
8/3/2014               0                        0                   1           
9/3/2014               1                        2                   0
10/3/2014              0                        0                   0
11/3/2014              0                        0                   0
```

Date will be passed dynamically, from 1 to 31st and have to get count records datewise of each employee?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself, beyond asking here?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can see this and understand .its self explanatory. Using pivot and unpivot you can overcome your problem.